# How do I use an environmental variable within my AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api, environment-variables

I included my API Key in my '.env' file which is hidden from Git.

*In .env file*

```
API_TOKEN=secrettokengibberish
```

Within my Angular controller, I want to access this variable when making my AJAX call.

*In StoryController.js*

```
var apiEndpoint = 'https://someapi.com/'+ $scope.myQuery +'.json?access_token=' + process.env.API_TOKEN;
```

The error that I keep getting when I do this is: **process is not defined at StoryController**

NOTE: I'm still learning Angular, so I'm not sure if this is even the right way to go about using API keys. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You are making a confusion here. Environment variables are defined in your NodeJS back end. Your Angular controllers run in the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you're trying to do:

```
+----------+         +---------+
|          | ---1--> |         |
| Frontend | <--2--- | Backend |
|          |         |         |
+----------+         +---------+
    |   A
    |   |           +-----+
    |   |           |     |
    |   \----4------| API |
    \----3--------->|     |
                    +-----+
```

Here is what you should be doing:

```
+----------+         +---------+         +-----+
|          | ---1--> |         | ---2--> |     |
| Frontend | <--4--- | Backend | <--3--- | API |
|          |         |         |         |     |
+----------+         +---------+         +-----+
```

Normally, you don't want your token to be publicly available in your frontend.

Consider creating a endpoint in your own backend and making it access the API instead of your frontend.

---

### Edit:

You do exactly as you'd be doing calling directly the API, but instead, you create this endpoint within your NodeJS backend. You'd probably want to use some framework like [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) (this is just an example):

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/:myQuery', function (req, res) {
    var apiEndpoint = 'https://someapi.com/'+ req.params.myQuery +'.json?access_token=' + process.env.API_TOKEN;
    http.get(apiEndpoint, function(apiResponse) {
        apiResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.status(apiResponse.statusCode);
        apiResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
           console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
           res.json(JSON.parse(chunk);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Then, in your frontend, your angular controller would do something like:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/+' + $scope.myQuery).then(function(){
   //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful diagram, Henrique.  Do you have an example of how to create an endpoint in the backend?  

Also, the reason I put this AJAX call in the front end is because I am taking in user input (i.e. $scope.myQuery) and adding it to my endpoint as a query - is there a way to do this after moving the endpoint to the backend?

Comment: Edited the answer to give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful for a n00b like me :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to have some type of authentication in angular on the front-end of your app.

Typically you would login on the front-end, and the back-end would return the user, token, and secret to the front-end which could then be used for future queries.  Any token hardcoded into your front-end code would be available to any user of your app.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not using this for auth, but I see what you're saying.

Would you ever make an AJAX call from the front-end that uses an API Token? (I'm using the Mapbox API)

Comment: If all users have the same token, then I would just add the token as a variable on your $rootScope ($rootScope.access_token = "Your App Access Token").  Due to javascript inheritance, variables defined on the rootScope will be available throughout your entire application.  I'm not familiar with the Mapbox api, but the above will make your access_token public.  If needed, you can avoid that by making an ajax request from the front-end to your back-end, then have the back-end append the token query parameters, and have the backend query the mapbox api and return the results back to the front-end